# JavaScript not working in Chrome Extension HTML desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, notifications, desktop

I'm developing a Chrome Extension with HTML desktop notifications, but when they show up, it looks like they don't execute any JavaScript. I started with a complex JS, then I reduced my test to this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>notification</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>document.write("content")</script>
    <img src='notification.png'><p>Yep!</p><p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see anything I hardcode but no DOM manipulation (or simple document.write) is working. I tried to put the JS in a separate file, but it didn't work. My current Chrome version is 23.0.1271.64 (Apple v.).

Can you help me?

[UPDATE] This is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "BB",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "",
  "icons": {"48": "BB.png"},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "BB",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bkg.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "notification.html","popup.html","popup.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What kind of of HTML file is that? Where do you want the action take place? What have you defined in your `manifest.json`? I think you need to do this in your content script, which is a javascript file anyway.

Comment: It is the HTML contained in the HTML desktop notification. The action takes place: I see my HTML file inside the desktop notification. But my JS is never executed (it should show the "content" word inside the notification popup).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an external script because of the [**Content Security Policy (CSP)**](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Here's how I got it working:

**background.js**

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('notification.html');
notification.show();
```

**notification.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>notification</title>
  <script src="notification.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='notification.png'><p>Yep!</p><p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the **notification.js**. It is important that you add an event listener to wait for the page to be loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test';
});
```

The text of the `p` tag should then be filled with the test content.

<sub>By the way: I don't think you need to add **notification.html** to your `web_accessible_resources`.</sub>

Comment: Now it works: maybe something strange happened after Chrome crashed. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hm, yeah strange things may happen; my whole profile crashed once. Since then I am using an own user for developing extensions. Glad to help, if I was of any :)

Comment: I've lost all my bookmarks after the crash. Another strange thing that happens (since yesterday) is that Chrome in an autonomous way, creates  new profiles... You can imagine my wife's face...   :-D